# No idea how to automate key presses in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to make a macro key presser for a game, in C#. But the problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to do so. I've looked online - even in Stack Overflow, but I can't find anything. I need to know how to automate key presses (for example, press it down and release it/tap a key). It also needs to be able to only press that key in the window the user is currently operating. Also, as I haven't figured it out yet, I need to know if it allows you to press another key (the key to stop the pressing of the other) in that window to exit the clicking.

It's a bit hard to explain, so I will make another post about it most likely ("it" referring to the text "Also, as I haven't figured it out yet, I need to know if it allows you to press another key (the key to stop the pressing of the other) in that window to exit the clicking.").

Some extra info:
I am using .NET Core for some reason.
I am using Visual Studio 2019.
My program is NOT a Windows Forms Program.
I am using Windows 10.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BedWarsDropBot
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BedWars Drop Bot.\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("This is a bot for dropping items on Bedwars. To start dropping, press V. To stop dropping, press X. To close, press Z.\n");
            var option = Console.ReadKey();
            bool check = true;
            switch (option.Key){
                case ConsoleKey.V:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your drop key/the key you would like to be pressed:\n");
                    var pressKey = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThe program is giving you 5 seconds to open up Bedwars, so that the program can start doing what it is meant to.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    while (check){
                        
                    };
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.X:
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Z:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou chose to close this program. Are you sure? [Y] [N]:\n");
                    var closeKey = Console.ReadKey();
                    switch (closeKey.Key){
                        case ConsoleKey.Y:
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                        case ConsoleKey.N:
                            Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use Windows APIs for this task. you can not find anything in Dotnet and c# itself. but its easy and possible to use winAPIs in c#

Comment: It's possible to use C#. like mentioned in the answers. But i personally would consider using AutoHotkey for something like this. Its a very powerfull tool, and worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SendKeys Method if you are adding a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send

Or you can directly use the `keybd_event` from the `user32.dll`.

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html

All these methods are working only on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SendKeys.Send("What ever you want it to type");
```

(only works if you have System.Windows.Forms dll installed)